# xcode, ios, Help Image Freezes, Not Moving

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to get an image to move to where I touch pixel by pixel.
But When I Run This And Press Somewhere The Image Moves To The Very Right Side Of The Screen and Doesn't Move After That.

The invisibleimage is a marker for where I touched and imageView is the image.

I know there is a way to do this because I've seen it in a game called Club Penguin.
Thanks For Your Help!

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
wheretouch1 = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if (imageView != nil) {
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
invisibleimage.center = wheretouch1;

[self performSelector:@selector(move:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

}

-(void)move:(id)sender{

if (CGPointEqualToPoint(imageView.center, invisibleimage.center)) {
    NSLog(@"At Destination");
}
if (imageView.center.x > invisibleimage.center.x){

    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x - 1, imageView.center.y);

    [self performSelector:@selector(move:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}
else if (imageView.center.x < invisibleimage.center.x){

    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + 1, imageView.center.y);

    [self performSelector:@selector(move:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}
if (imageView.center.y > invisibleimage.center.y) {

    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.y - 1, imageView.center.y);

    [self performSelector:@selector(move:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}
else if (imageView.center.y < invisibleimage.center.y){

    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.y + 1, imageView.center.y);

    [self performSelector:@selector(move:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gesture Recognizer works this way:
[image: UIGestureRecognizerStates]

So in your code move: will be called once, when user tap.

Create a property NSTimer *timer and inside touchBegan add this code:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(move:) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
```

And inside of touchEnded and touchCancelled add `[self.timer invalidate];` to stop timer when touch finish.

Comment: It asks me to replace . with ->
This is what I Put In ViewController.h:
NSTimer *timer;

ViewController.m:
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.timer invalidate];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.timer invalidate];
}